# Digital signing in java applet using eclipse

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#11

I am trying to sign some data (a POST form) in a web based application using a Java Applet. The user's x509 certificate would be in a cryptoken/smart card. 
I am using this tutorial/code as a starting point in building the applet - http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.php/3587361/Java-Applet-for-Signing-with-a-Smart-Card.htm

I could build and run the applet in browser, but i get error while signing the file as "Cannot open the file for reading"
any helps and suggestion?